# The correct way to store some metadata associated with an object?

Tags: c#, caching, memory-leaks, metadata

Firstly I'm afraid of the memory leak issue here. Because what I do is using some Dictionary to store the metadata with Key of the object itself. So I can lookup for metadata (which should be dynamic) by passing in the object.

Note that the object here does not have any GUID to help identify itself, the only way to identify it is by its instance.
This kind of storing looks much like what in `DependencyObject` in WPF. We can declare `DependencyProperty` (attached property) to extend the `DependencyObject` (the metadata is contained in the attached property).

Here is what I have:

```
Dictionary<object, SomeMetaData> _metadataLookup = new Dictionary<object,SomeMetaData>();
//to store metadata
_metadataLookup[someObject] = someMetaData;
//to get metadata
SomeMetaData someMetaData;
_metadataLookup.TryGetValue(someObject, out someMetaData);
```

It would be fine if the `someObject`'s lifetime is the same as the lifetime of the scope using the `_metadataLookup`. But what if the `someObject` (after stored in `_metadataLookup`) should be destroyed (logically become unused)? We have to manually remove it from `_metadataLookup` as well, otherwise there is a memory leak there.

I'm seeking for a better solution for this issue, unexpectedly forgetting to remove the objects manually or simply not knowing when the objects should be removed is a problem here. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah storing the reference is probably not a good thing. however you could store the hashcode, though you will have to implement it properly

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks, are you sure that the Hash code could help identify the objects without any contention?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this purpose you can use [ConditionalWeakTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var mc1 = new ManagedClass();
      var mc2 = new ManagedClass();
      var mc3 = new ManagedClass();

      var cwt = new ConditionalWeakTable<ManagedClass, ClassData>();
      cwt.Add(mc1, new ClassData());          
      cwt.Add(mc2, new ClassData());
      cwt.Add(mc3, new ClassData());

      var wr2 = new WeakReference(mc2);
      mc2 = null;

      GC.Collect();

      ClassData data = null; 

      if (wr2.Target == null)
          Console.WriteLine("No strong reference to mc2 exists.");   
      else if (cwt.TryGetValue(mc2, out data))
          Console.WriteLine("Data created at {0}", data.CreationTime);      
      else
          Console.WriteLine("mc2 not found in the table.");
   }
}

public class ManagedClass
{ 
}

public class ClassData
{
   public DateTime CreationTime;
   public object Data;   

   public ClassData()
   {
      CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
      this.Data  = new object();     
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       No strong reference to mc2 exists.
```

Comment: thank you for this, it looks like that the `ConditionalWeakTable` is a tool of compiler services. Is it fine to just use it in our own code? I'm afraid of its change in future. One more thing I would like to have here is some concurrent version of this `ConditionalWeakTable`? Yes actually in my scenario I may have to lookup for the data concurrently. Anyway this answer is great but I still leave this question open for a while. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hopeless, as docs said: _Instances of the ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue> class are thread safe. They do not require callers to do any additional locking._

Comment: @Hopeless it's hard to tell, is it ok or not. But `ConditionalWeakTable` seems ok for situation you have described

Comment: thanks, at least I have no other way, maybe some look into the source code of WPF for implementation of `DependencyObject` and `DependencyProperty` will provide another solution.